# Referencing a project with a folder that should be copied

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

I have MasterProject (MP) and ReferencedProject (RP). RP has a directory of files that I am currently copying to its output bin directory with a post-build event.

I'm referencing RP from MP and would like the directory of files from RP to be copied to the MP output directory. What would be the best way to do this.

Having to add a build-event in MP to reference the directory in RP feels dirty! Is there a better way?